# How to generate a JSONPath from a Java field?

Tags: java, jackson, jsonpath

Is there a way to generate a JSONPath based on a Java field? For example:

```
class Person {
    List<Friends> friends;
}

class Friends {
    String name;
}
```

If I want to generate the JSONPath ($.person.friends[*].name) to get to the Person.friends.name, is there a Java library to does that?